# Override review summary.phtml under custom template

Tags: magento2, product-review, custom-template

I want to override `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml` under my custom template.

I created the phtml file under `app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Module_Review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The path is incorrect. It should be `app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Module_Review/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml` (remove `view/frontend/`).

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Do you have your custom theme selected with the correct config and inheritance?

Comment: Sure, I've made many changes before.

Comment: Ok, just figured I'd make sure. Is the site in developer mode?

Answer (score 0):

Need to be Magento_Review, not Module_Review as folder name in app/design (Vendor_Module).

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be like this,
`app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Magento_Review/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml`

Insted of this,

`app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Module_Review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml`